# Is there an analog of $\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda = \eta$ in any representation of the restricted Lorentz group?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors

The  Lorentz group $O(1,3)$ is defined by
$$\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda = \eta \quad(1)$$
which we call the defining representation.

Given an irreducible representation of the restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3)$, for instance the (left) spinor representation $(1/2,0)$, we can define a `spinor metric' $g$ by
$$
(\sigma^i)^T g + g (\sigma^i) = 0
$$
where $\{ \sigma^i\}_{i=1,2,3}$ are the Pauli matrices. Then it's not difficult to derive that
$$
g_{ab} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & c  \\
    -c & 0
  \end{bmatrix}, \quad c\in\mathbb R
$$

So we can choose $c=1$ and we recover the spinor metric found in most books (although imo they are often simply stated without further motivation).

My question is:

Following the same reasoning, does **any** irreducible  representation of the restricted Lorentz group induce a (representation dependent) metric and if so is the method above basically only way to derive these induced metrics?

Comment: I suspect you'd work out your answer much more easily if you suspended your focus on the Lorentz group which distracts and disorients students by its peculiarity and reviewed your rotation group, O(3) ~ SU(2)/Z_2  instead. The analog condition is R^T  R = I in 3d which, orthogonal rotation matrices, specifies the su(2) Lie algebra of angular momentum. You'd then note that same algebra has a smaller representation (the Pauli matrices acting on 2-spinors), without the geometrical distraction of the above condition. The argument carries over to the Lorentz group without a hitch!

Comment: @CosmasZachos You're right: I was too distracted by the peculiarity of the Lorentzian metric. Since $\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda = \eta$ is saying the same thing as $\Lambda^T \Lambda = 1$, and the latter holds for any representation, then also in for example the $(1/2,0)$ representation we must have $D(\Lambda^T) g \Lambda = g$. Now of course the components of the`spinor metric' $g$ are not given but must/can be found from knowledge of the representation $D(\Lambda)$ and the identity $D(\Lambda^T) g \Lambda = g$. This is what you mean isn't it?

Comment: Not really... Your first condition is for O(1,3), the second for O(4). For the rotation group I sent you to, The defining rep has orthogonal matrices, but the doublet/spinor one Unitary ones...

Comment: @CosmasZachos arghh, sorry, I don't know myself anymore why I kept writing the transpose for the Lorentz group. Again apologies, I'll edit my question when I have worked it out properly.

Comment: The [mainstream language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group) is here... make sure you stick to it...